# Why is this Sql Geography "Valid" on SQL Server 2014 and "Invalid" on Azure SQL?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

Here's the query. Sorry it's in a paste-bin link and not in this question, but the geography data is longer than the maximum characters for the question!

http://pastebin.com/i0t1sqQR

There's two versions of the query there.

The first is the normal query, it runs fine on 2014, but on Azure Sql I get:

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography": 
System.ArgumentException: 24200: The specified input does not represent a valid geography instance. Use MakeValid to convert the instance to a valid instance. Note that MakeValid may cause the points of a spatial instance to shift slightly.
System.ArgumentException: 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography..ctor(GeoData g, Int32 srid)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromBinary(OpenGisType type, SqlBytes wkbGeography, Int32 srid)
```

The second version is with .MakeValid() added. Again it runs fine on 2014, but I get the exact same error again on Azure Sql.

Why is this behaving differently?

Why doesn't MakeValid() work?

---

As a side note ... where is the documentation for the differences between Sql Server and Azure Sql?

I've found a blog post from 2014: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rbrundritt/archive/2014/08/18/working-with-invalid-geography-objects-in-sql-azure.aspx

That references patch notes form 2011: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6197.updated-spatial-features-in-the-sql-azure-q4-2011-service-release.aspx

So MakeValid was shown in the table in the article as working, but had a note saying "actually this doesn't work at all" and that was the only indication of that issue for 3 years?

Comment: The article says Azure does not allow invalid Geographies at all. Your code does not even get to call MakeValid. Fails before that. Does that explain the issue?

Comment: Unfortunatly not. The Geography is valid in Sql 2014, it doesn't require the MakeValid call to work. I added MakeValid as something to try since that's what the error message suggests.

Comment: On Azure there can't be invalid Geo. Do you understand that? There is no way to construct such a value. "Why doesn't MakeValid() work?" Because it is never called on Azure. On Azure it is a no-op as the article states.

Comment: Yes I do understand that. Thank you for trying to answer that last question which is simply about a possible solution that doesn't work. However the actual question is "Why is this Sql Geography “Valid” on SQL Server 2014 and “Invalid” on Azure SQL?". Might I suggest stepping away from the keyboard for a bit? You seem a bit burned out.

Comment: That must be from answering 3000 times.

Comment: Absolutely! It can be very tiring interacting with people wanting/demanding help every day. I used to hang out in a help chat channel, but I eventually moved on as I found it very draining, especially when people appeared not to put any effort in. I have tried to put effort in here and I do understand what the article is saying. But the article isn't directly relevant to the question which is why I put it in a separate section as a "side note". If I could make you a cup of tea/buy you a beer for all the great work you've done on SO, I would! p.s. you're almost at 4000!

Comment: Thank you Andy. All the experienced Stack Overflow members have acquired ways of being a little forceful. It's often necessary to expedite the process. Here, it's not :) Unfortunately, I don't know how to answer the question (which I now understand).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that the first geography isn't valid in either case (i.e. on premises SQL or Azure). If I take the code from your pastebin link and transform it slightly to:

```
exec sp_executesql N'
DECLARE @Location geography = geography::STGeomFromWKB(@wkb, 4326);
SELECT  @Location.STIsValid()
',N'@wkb varbinary(max)',@wkb=0x0106...
```

I get back 0 (i.e. false). That said, I don't know why the on prem version of SQL is able to display the first geography instance; typically a precondition for that is that it's valid.

If this is a one-time operation, maybe using the seemingly less restrictive on prem version to generate a valid geography which you can then export to Azure will work for you.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for this. I've been looking at this over the afternoon and found the same thing. Apparently Sql 2014 is more than happy to work with invalid geographies, which is pretty much the opposite of what Azure Sql does :/ I've tried calling MakeValid on the data in Sql 2014 and while the result is different it also returns 0 for STIsValid. It seems Sql 2014 is happy to work with an invalid geography, but can't make it valid. I tried popping the WKT in this tool: http://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html and it drew it fine.

Comment: Yeah. My local version of SQL doesn't have any problem drawing it. It just thinks it's invalid. I, however, get a different result when I call `STIsValid()` on the instance returned by `MakeValid()`. That is, I get that it is indeed a valid instance. @@version returns "12.0.2269.0 (X64)" for me if that matters.

Comment: 12.0.4213.0 (X64) for me ... oh well. You are indeed correct, it's not valid on either, it's just 2014 is able to handle it. That answers the core question.